# dotnet build/msbuild fails on GenerateResource Task with .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I try to build my project in my CI/CD pipeline with a gitlab runner, but I always end in the following error message:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3264,5): error MSB4216: The GenerateResource task could not be performed because MSBuild could not create a task host or connect to a task host with runtime CLR4 and architecture x86.  Make sure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture is available on the computer and (2) the required executable file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be executed. [project_path]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3286,7): error MSB4028: The output of the GenerateResource task could not be retrieved from the FilesWritten parameter. Object does not match target type. [project_path]
```

I´ve installed .NET6 SDK with version 6.0.100.
It seems like its trying to find the msbuild.exe and it´s not there. I´ve copied the file temporarely but this causes a endless building without result or error message.

Am I missing something? In my Visual Studio 2022 the build process is working and generating my binaries.